# If $f$ is increasing toward $1$, then $\sup\{f(x)\sin x \}=1$

Tags: calculus, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Suppose $f$ is an increasing monotone function in $(0,\infty)$.

If

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=1$$
then 
$$\sup\{f(x)\sin x\mid x>0\}=1$$

I am not really sure how to approach this, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For large $x$ what can you say about $f(x)$ and for large $x$ what can you say about $\sin x$?

Comment: Umm, for large x's, f(x) is getting closer to 1, and $\sin x$ is between -1 to 1

Comment: You're almost there!

Comment: @paw88789 I'm getting the feel this is not true, but I don't know how to prove it, since in given function, x gets value are closer to 1, but the function could be not defined in $x=1$, since $\sin x$ between -1 to 1, therefore $f(x)\sin x$ would never "reach" to x=1

Comment: The function value doesn't have to reach the sup; it just has to get really close.

Comment: You right my bad, so actually this is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin (x)=1$ iff $x=\dfrac{1}{2}(\pi + 4n \pi)$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so define $\{ x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subset \mathbb{R}$ by $x_n = \dfrac{1}{2}(\pi + 4n \pi)$, then
$$\sup g(x_n) = \sup f(x_n)\sin(x_n)=\sup f(x_n)\cdot 1 = \sup f(x_n) $$
and then conclude!